# Spring app seems to start in debug, but can't connect to it

Tags: spring, spring-boot, debugging, web

i was making web shop in spring boot and just out of the blue, when I started my app in debug mode I couldn't connect to it.
But, when i start the app in non-debug mode, it works.

I tried opening it from different browsers and deleting the cache of the browser, using postman, also i tried making another copy of the project and that did work for the initial startup, then just stopped working in the same manner.
The console shows normal messages and looks like it is starting normally.

I copied the console logs into ChatGPT and asked him if something is wrong, it said it seemed like the app is started normally on port 8080.

Stack  trace where I think the problem can be seen:

```
2023-06-17T11:32:07.640+02:00  WARN 3456 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000026: PostgreSQL94Dialect has been deprecated; use org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect instead
2023-06-17T11:32:08.856+02:00  INFO 3456 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2023-06-17T11:32:08.866+02:00  INFO 3456 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-06-17T11:32:09.220+02:00  WARN 3456 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Cannot deserialize session attribute [SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT] for session [D8E4441C61226F2C2A03072390F42807]
2023-06-17T11:32:50.494+02:00  WARN 3456 --- [  restartedMain] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
```

Also, at one point I got this error "invalid type code: FF" and after that i could not debug the code.

Comment: What do you mean by unable to connect? Do you see errors in the logs?

Comment: NO errors, just the browser telling me cant connect. There are warnings for deprecated Thymeleaf expressions, but I don't think that should cause any problems

Comment: please add the full startup log

Comment: Will do if the problem occurs again, which I think it will. For now I cloned the project again and now it can run in debug. Before anyone asks, yes I committed all the changes to the code as the project that couldn't be connect to in debug.

Comment: Did you run it in Intellij?

Comment: Yes, I use intellij Ultimate

Comment: Could you take a look at the stack trace?

Comment: Please show the whole log. What you showed is not the issue